# Отправка post запроса ajax в php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Нужно посмотреть какие данные приходят в `php`. Выполняется запрос при нажатии кнопки:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("#product_form");
form.addEventListener("submit", sendForm);

function sendForm(e) { 
  //e.preventDefault(); 
  $.ajax(
    { 
      url: "main.php",
      data: { // данные, которые будут отправлены на сервер 
        name: "Denis",
        city: "Erebor"
      },
      method: 'POST',
      processData: true,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json'
});
```

```html
<form action="main.php" id="product_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`main.php` c кодом `print_r($_POST);` показывает пустой массив `Array()`.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, используется `method: "POST"` вместо `type: 'POST'`.

Comment: Что означает `contentType: false`?, опять же, насколько я знаю, это недопустимое значение заголовка `contentType`.

Comment: Я в `AJAX'е JQ` не силён, но разве не надо добавлять `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',`?

Comment: @V-Mor, `type` - с версии 1.9 это алиас для `method`. На работоспособность не сказывается, но предпочтительнее  `method`.

Comment: Тут же нет колбека на success. Как вы выяснили что показывается пустой массив?

Comment: @u_mulder перехожу на main.php по дефолту

Comment: И в итоге у вас и сабмит в джсе обрабатывается и обычный сабмит. Два сабмита. Смотрите в `preventDefault`

Comment: `//e.preventDefault();`  раскоментируйте.. И в network смотрите ответ

Comment: @V-Mor до jq 1.9 использовать надо type, 1.9+ -> method (хотя type вроде как тоже не запрещён..)

Comment: Посмотрите в нетворке, что отправляется?

Answer (score 0):

`contentType` должен быть `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

По умолчанию он так и стоит. Вам не нужно было указывать другое значение

Answer (score 0):

Можно убрать тег `<form>` - чтобы избежать ошибки двойной отправки формы. Так же уберите у кнопки `type="submit"` нажатие кнопки вас и перенаправляет на страницу обработчика и post не успевает отработать. Отлавливайте событие `click` а кнопке дайте `type="button"`

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#send");
button.addEventListener("click", sendForm);

   function sendForm(e) {  
   $.ajax({
    method: 'post', 
    url: "main.php", 
    data: ({
        name: "Denis",
        city: "Erebor"
    }),
    success: function(data){
        //обработка ответа от вашего main.php
    }
});
   }
```

```html
<div id="product_form" >
  <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
  <input type="button" id="send" name="Send">
</div>
```

В обработчике лучше сначала проверять так:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
}
```

**Вообще это плохой тон, смешивать jquery и js. В Js есть прекрасный метод fetch для подобного. А если вам нужен именно jquery то используйте что-то типа такого: $("#send").on('click', function(){//здесь ваша функция});**

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю следующее решение:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var data = {
  'name': 'dima',
  'arr': arr,
};
$.ajax({
  url: "main.php",
  data: data,
  method: 'POST',
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

[Здесь](https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_method_ajax.php) довольно подробно расписано, что и зачем.

Comment: Зачем эти костыли? Можно использовать и просто `$.post`.

Comment: @And, да это кому как удобнее. Тоже всегда использую полную версию `$.ajax`.

Comment: @And Насколько я понял, вопрос был конкретно про использование метода `$.ajax`

Comment: main.php показывает  пустой массив

Comment: @ДмитрийСухоцкий Попробуйте установить `processData: true`.